# Why is my chained Django queryset not working?

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(
    zipcode=request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips1
).filter(
    zipcode=request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips2
).filter(
    zipcode=request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips3
)
```

This does not seem to return any `Entry` objects, even though it should.

Note: If I were to remove all the chaining it just leave the initial `nearbyzips1` filter, it returns all `Entry` objects that match that zipcode.  So this tells me that my chaining is breaking something.

What am I doing incorrectly?

I am not using any m2m or foreign keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you need to find all entries containing one of the given zipcodes. The correct approach is:

```
Entry.objects.filter(zipcode__in=[
    request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips1,
    request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips2,
    request.user.my_profile.nearbyzips3
])
```

This query returns all entries having as zipcode one of the values of the array. The query you gave just tries to find all entries with zipcode equal to all given zipcodes at the same time. So it's normal to return nothing.

Comment: Oh cool, this is KIND OF what I attempted to do earlier, but I guess I had the wrong syntax.  Thanks I'll give this a shot.

Comment: just put all of it in one line

Comment: Take a look in to PEP8 to learn how to write good code & this should help ; http://pep8online.com/
The last thing you want to do is write everything on one line.